# Highcharter - specific colors for line and scatter groups

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a graph where I am comparing plants labor time and averages with each other. The data comes from two different sets and I would like "Plant A"'s scatter plot color to be the same color as "Plant A"'s average line (and so on).

I've learned I have to assign the colors to the plant name because Highcharter color coordinates by cronological order and the data is always sorted by Time, not Plant Name.

When I do this however, I am able to get the correct color for the scatter plot but the line won't take the same color. The marker on the line does, but not the physical line. (Also, it looks like the legend isn't taking the color assignments at all).

Below is a reproducible example of my issue:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (date)
library (tidyr)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)


Plant.Name <- c("PlantB","PlantA","PlantC","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC")
Date <- c("1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/3/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/4/2018","1/4/2018")
Time <- c(5,6,4,3,6,5,2,1,4,3,1,3,5,2)

Ship_data <- data.frame(cbind(Plant.Name,Date,Time))
Ship_data$Plant.Name <- as.character(Ship_data$Plant.Name)
Ship_data$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(Ship_data$Time))
Ship_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(Ship_data$Date))

Ship_data <- mutate(Ship_data, coloract = ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantA", "#A1CAF1", 
                                                 ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantB", "#BE0032",
                                                        ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantC", "#C2B280",
                                                               "#000000"
                                                        ))))

Plant.Name <- c("PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC")
Date <- c("1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018")
Average <- c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)

Avg_data <- data.frame(cbind(Plant.Name,Date,Average))
Avg_data$Plant.Name <- as.character(Avg_data$Plant.Name)
Avg_data$Average <- as.numeric(as.character(Avg_data$Average))
Avg_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(Avg_data$Date))

Avg_data <- mutate(Avg_data, coloract = ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantA", "#A1CAF1", 
                                                 ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantB", "#BE0032",
                                                        ifelse(Plant.Name == "PlantC", "#C2B280",
                                                               "#000000"
                                                        ))))



hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = Ship_data, hcaes(x=Date, y = Time, group = Plant.Name, color = coloract), 
                type = "scatter", marker = list(radius = 2)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = Avg_data, hcaes(x=Date, y = Average, color = coloract, group = Plant.Name), 
                type = "line", marker = list(enabled = FALSE))  %>%
  hc_yAxis(min = 0, title = list(text = "Labor Hours")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%b %d %Y')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 1)

hc
```

Update:
Found a solution that works but it's not the most eloquent solution. Hoping someone has a better one out there. I added a "PlantD" because my normal code is dynamic and not all plants may be displayed depending on user input.

```
library (ggplot2)
library (date)
library (tidyr)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)


Plant.Name <- c("PlantB","PlantA","PlantC","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC")
Date <- c("1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/3/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/4/2018","1/4/2018")
Time <- c(5,6,4,3,6,5,2,1,4,3,1,3,5,2)

Ship_data <- data.frame(cbind(Plant.Name,Date,Time))
Ship_data$Plant.Name <- as.character(Ship_data$Plant.Name)
Ship_data$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(Ship_data$Time))
Ship_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(Ship_data$Date))

Plant.Name <- c("PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantA","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantB","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC","PlantC")
Date <- c("1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018","1/1/2018","1/2/2018","1/3/2018","1/4/2018")
Average <- c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)

Avg_data <- data.frame(cbind(Plant.Name,Date,Average))
Avg_data$Plant.Name <- as.character(Avg_data$Plant.Name)
Avg_data$Average <- as.numeric(as.character(Avg_data$Average))
Avg_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(Avg_data$Date))

 hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_yAxis(min = 0, title = list(text = "Labor Hours")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%b %d %Y')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 1)
  if (nrow(Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantA",]) == 0) {} else {
    hc <- hc %>%
    hc_add_series(data = Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantA",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Time, group = Plant.Name), 
                  type = "scatter", marker = list(radius = 2),color = "#A1CAF1") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = Avg_data[Avg_data$Plant.Name == "PlantA",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Average, group = Plant.Name),
                  type = "line", marker = list(enabled = FALSE),color = "#A1CAF1")}
  if (nrow(Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantB",]) == 0) {} else {
    hc <- hc %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantB",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Time, group = Plant.Name), 
                    type = "scatter", marker = list(radius = 2),color = "#BE0032") %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Avg_data[Avg_data$Plant.Name == "PlantB",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Average, group = Plant.Name),
                    type = "line", marker = list(enabled = FALSE),color = "#BE0032")} 
  if (nrow(Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantC",]) == 0) {} else {
    hc <- hc %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantC",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Time, group = Plant.Name), 
                    type = "scatter", marker = list(radius = 2),color = "#C2B280") %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Avg_data[Avg_data$Plant.Name == "PlantC",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Average, group = Plant.Name),
                    type = "line", marker = list(enabled = FALSE),color = "#C2B280")} 
  if (nrow(Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantD",]) == 0) {} else {
    hc <- hc %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Ship_data[Ship_data$Plant.Name == "PlantD",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Time, group = Plant.Name), 
                    type = "scatter", marker = list(radius = 2),color = "#604E97") %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Avg_data[Avg_data$Plant.Name == "PlantD",], hcaes(x=Date, y = Average, group = Plant.Name),
                    type = "line", marker = list(enabled = FALSE),color = "#604E97")} 

hc
```

Comment: Have you considered using `zones` for coloring the line segments? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones